# Python inheritance: confusing arg with kwarg

Tags: python-2.7, inheritance

If I run the following code:

```
class A(object) :

    def __init__(self, x, y, z=3.0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

class B(A):

    def __init__(self, a, b, c="c", *args, **kwargs):
        super(B, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c


if __name__=="__main__":

    thing = B("a", "b", 1, 2)

    print thing.x # expect 1
    print thing.y # expect 2
    print thing.z # expect 3
    print thing.a # expect a
    print thing.b # expect b
    print thing.c # expect c
```

Instead I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/Python/Random Scripts/python_inheritance.py", line 23, in <module>
    thing = B(1,2,"a","b")
  File "H:/Python/Random Scripts/python_inheritance.py", line 15, in __init__
    super(B, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

It seems like python is parsing the third argument "a" as the kwarg argment c instead of as an arg. How do I get the behaviour that I expect?

I can obviously do :

```
class B(A):

    def __init__(self, a, b, *args, **kwargs):
        self.c = kwargs.pop("c", "c")
        super(B, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

but it seems in every way horrible.

Comment: Putting `c="c"` in the function definition doesn't make `c` a keyword-only argument. The uses of `=whatever` in a function definition and a function call are completely, absolutely, 100% unrelated. `=whatever` in a function definition just means the argument value defaults to `whatever` if no value is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two lines from your code, aligned to show which value is assigned to each name:

```
def __init__(self, a,   b,  c="c", *args, **kwargs):

        thing = B("a", "b", 1,     2)
```

As you can see, the `1` is assigned to `c`, leaving only one argument in the variadic `args` list.  The problem is that there are not two "classes" of argument in the way that you assume: whereas you call `c` a "kwarg argument" it isn't really defined as such, any more than `a` is. Both could be addressed by calling `B(b="b", **some_dict)` assuming `some_dict` had both an `'a'` and a `'c'` entry.   Instead of a definitional dichotomy between args and kwargs, there are just arguments that have specified default values, and arguments that do not.

I think you're right that `kwargs.pop()` is your best bet.  My code is littered with such "horrible" examples.